# Redirect stdout / stderr output to log file with timestamp

Tags: io-redirection, timestamps

I'm trying to redirect the stdout and stderr to a log file. The filename should be created dynamically with current timestamp.

I can create the filename with the following command:

```
$ date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.txt
2018-04-10_16-55-55.txt
```

So I want to do something like this:

```
mycommand &> (date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.txt)
```

But this doesn't work (`` -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(' ``)

Comment: Similar (no dupe): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/436800/how-to-pass-argument-to-subshell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you will need to use a command substitution:

```
mycommand &> "$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.txt)"
```

Which is `bash`-speak for

```
mycommand  >"$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.txt)" 2>&1
```

Which is the same as

```
mycommand  >"$(date +%F_%H-%M-%S.txt)" 2>&1
```

(`%F` is the same as `%Y-%m-%d`)

A command substitution, `$(...)`, will be replaced by the output of the command inside.

What you used was a sub-shell, `(...)`. A sub-shell can't accept redirections like that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
today=`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S`; mycommand > ${today}.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: Using bash on CentOS, I needed to escape the `%` symbols, like this: `\%`.