# How to pass argument to subshell

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, command

Is it possible to pass **DBNAME** argument to subshell without manually writing it?

```
mysqldump -u USERNAME -p DBNAME > "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")_DBNAME.sql"
```

Comment: Similar (no dupe): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/436784/redirect-stdout-stderr-output-to-log-file-with-timestamp

Answer (score 1):

There is no sub-shell here, but a command substitution (the `$(...)`).  If `DBNAME` is a variable, you can use

```
DBNAME=mydatabase
mysqldump -u USERNAME -p "$DBNAME" > "$(date +"%F_%H-%M-%S")_$DBNAME.sql"
```

or even

```
DBNAME=mydatabase
mysqldump -u USERNAME -p "$DBNAME" >"$(date +"%F_%H-%M-%S_$DBNAME.sql")"
```

or

```
DBNAME=mydatabase
outfilename=$(date +"%F_%H-%M-%S_$DBNAME.sql")
mysqldump -u USERNAME -p "$DBNAME" >"$outfilename"
```

or variations thereof.